# Github enterprise - remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

My git was working fine, then without changing anything than the following problem started to happen,
I have tried resetting the cache in

> credentials.helper

and have gone through pretty much every stackoverflow answer I could find

```
remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations.
remote: You must use a personal access token or SSH key.
remote: See https://github.ibm.com/settings/tokens or
'https://github.ibm.com/WBurney/Blockchain_SDO.git/': 
The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Thanks

Comment: `I have tried resetting the cache` ... what did you actually do?  You may have read many answers but we don't know what you did to get to this state.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you have registered a public ssh key to your GitHub enterprise account, you could side-step the issue using an ssh url

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote set-url origin git@github.ibm.com:WBurney/Blockchain_SDO.git
```

Then any command like `git push`/`git fetch`/`git pull`/`git ls-remote` would use the SSH URL set by `git remote set-url`.

But regarding your original issue, try and follow "[Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/)".

If you are on Mac, [update your credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/).

You might need to [remove an old cached credential first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59890860/6309).
(As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903106/github-enterprise-remote-password-authentication-is-not-available-for-git-ope/45905230#comment108297615_45905230) by [RayLoveless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462971/rayloveless))

As [drazen Bjelovuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107110/drazen-bjelovuk) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903106/github-enterprise-remote-password-authentication-is-not-available-for-git-ope/45905230#comment136462151_45905230):

> Updating the password to a personal token in my OSX Keychain worked for me.

Comment: I followed the following steps to add my ssh keys to git
https://git.ng.bluemix.net/help/ssh/README.md
Then i set the remote URL using 
git remote set-url origin git@github.ibm.com:WBurney/Blockchain_SDO.git
Thanks for help

Comment: @MuhammadRaafayKhan What is your OS and git version?

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 and git version 2.11.0

Comment: You may have to clear your credentials cache so you get prompted to enter your password/token:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git

Comment: @RayLoveless True: "erase" command on Mac or "reject" on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59890860/6309

Comment: Worked for me using ssh . What if I want to do using http ?

Comment: @NoobCoder First, that would be HTTPS, not HTTP. Second, as mentioned in the answer, the best practice would be to use a PAT (Personal Access Token) as a password (and your GitHub user account name as a login)

Comment: The Mac one worked for me. I was trying to clone a repo from IntelliJ and this error was coming up. Deleted the IntelliJ github entry in Keychain. Then tried to clone the repo and logged in with access token. It worked fine. Thanks 

Comment: git push is not needed.

Comment: @tedyyu You are correct. I have edited the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Updating credentials in key chain worked for me.

Comment: Updating the password to a personal token in my OSX Keychain worked for me.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 46):

Another solution that worked for me was **changing the credentials via the Windows Credentials Manager**:

1) Clear your cached credentials (thanks @[Rayloveless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462971/rayloveless)).

2) Follow the steps in [this link](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) to create an access token.

- In the upper-right corner of any page, click your profile photo.
- Click Settings
- In the left sidebar, click Developer settings
- Personal access tokens
- Generate new Token

3) Go to "Windows Credential Manager" and look for your Github Enterprise account.

4) Click modify and replace the password with the token you generated.

Comment: Adding link is ok, but you should provide an example to keep your answer valid in case the link is deleted

Comment: This was the one that did it for me. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. I needed to clear my cached credentials.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me.

Comment: This does the trick!

Answer (score 16):

Try below one -

```
git clone https://<user-name>:<git-token>@<github-path.git>
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to reset the credential. Open GIT CMD and type below command

```
git credential reject
```

press enter. The cursor would be waiting for the next input. Then type

```
protocol=https
host=git.example.com
```

Replace git.example.com, with your link.

Press "enter" twice so let git know that's the end of the command. Now you need two things before any git operations as it will first validate your username and password.

1. Username - It would present near your logo under signed in as. Example this is mine. Give the exact username -

[image]

2. Password -

- Click Settings
- In the left sidebar, click Developer settings
- Personal access tokens
- Generate new Token (copy this token somewhere. It won't show up again)

Next, go to git cmd and do your git operation.
for example -

`git clone https://consulting-github.com/Rohan-Chikorde/example.git`

Once started, it will prompt for username and password. Give the username example: `Rohan-Chikorde` and password: `e67682yourgeneratedtoken` as described above and you would be good to go.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer will work only for ssh, not for https.

The cache reset commends seems to have recently changed. For me that eventually made it work.

```
git credential reject
protocol=https
host=github.<YOUR_COMP>.com
```

Comment: Need to enter a blank line at the end (press <Enter> twice) to indicate that you are finished adding data.

Answer (score 3):

for me it was an easy process to go as

1. generate my [token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)
2. `git remote remove origin`
3. `git remote add origin https://<token>@<git_url>.git`
4. now try the **command**(push,pull,..) again.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I deleted the old generated token and generated new one and used that

Answer (score 0):

First you should try to generate Personal Access Token(PAT) and then put it in Credential Manager as a password to your GitHub.
For that: Go to Credentials Manager > Windows Credentials > GitHub(Under generic credentials).
Now put your PAT as a password.

If you are still not able to clone the repo then try the method given in one of the answers here by Ajay, it worked for me once:
git clone `https://<user-name>:<git-token>@<github-path.git>`

Answer (score -5):

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.ibm.com:WBurney/Blockchain_SDO.git
```

The above git command will works