# Git Hub remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations

Tags: github, git-push, tortoisegit, git-clone

I am new to tortoise git and using for my Github enterprise. When I try to commit my files from Tortoise git , it works but when I try to push it throws me the below error

remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations.

remote: You must use a personal access token or SSH key.

remote: See https://github.********.com/settings/tokens or https://github.******.com/settings/ssh
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.ford.com/****/****.git/':

The requested URL returned error: 403

I get the same error when I try to clone. I can only commit files.

But when i try using with a sample github.com instead of enterprise, all works fine. 
Please advice me on this.

If i need to set up anything for authentication guide me as well

Comment: Use either SSH for Git remote operations or create an App token which you use instead of your password.

Comment: Already addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903106/github-enterprise-remote-password-authentication-is-not-available-for-git-ope

Answer (score 8):

You can create an access token and store it in the Windows Credential Manager.

- Follow the steps in [this link](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) to create an access token.
- Go to "Windows Credential Manager" and look for your Github Enterprise account.
- Click modify and replace the password with the token you generated.

Answer (score 0):

Generating Your SSH Public Key and replacing it as GitHub password should help.

**Step 1** : Go to your IDE>>terminal - run below cmd & follow next steps populated

```
 $ ssh-keygen -o
```

**Step 2** : Wait for some time and verify if given `<filename.pub>` has been generated in `<given path>`

**Step 3** : Replace generated .pub key as a password for GitHub account.

Windows users go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`. Click `Windows Credentials`, look for GitHub account, select and edit password to .pub key

[image]

**Refer** [Generating Your SSH Public Key](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Generating-Your-SSH-Public-Key)

Answer (score -2):

There are two ways of authenticating :

1. either using username / password prompt while each git push/pull/clone
2. Setup SSH Keys and let your rsa keys authenticate you ( which is widely preferred).

I think ford has opted the approach 2 .

The below article from Github should help you out.

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Follow it and make sure u add the SSH key of all machines u want access to the repo.

Comment: I did the same and added SSH key to my github as well, but it did not work out. Still gives me the same error.  Cloning into 'C:\Users\Shankaran\Documents\Github test\aem-spl'...
remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations.
remote: You must use a personal access token or SSH key.
remote: See https://github.ford.com/settings/tokens or https://github.ford.com/settings/ssh
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.ford.com/****/***.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: make sure you are using the clone url as something that starts with git@github.com:* , which has to be used if using ssh auth. If you are using a clone url that starts with http , its gonna take the 1st approach as mentioned in answer