# push issue in Git from windows using gitbash

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I have generated the SSH key and updated the same in the Git repository. Later tried to push the code but end up with the following error. I tried the workarounds associated in stakeoverflow and in google as well but not solved. Could please advise.

remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations.
remote: You must use a personal access token or SSH key.
remote: See https://github.xxx.com/settings/tokens or https://github.xxx.com/settings/ssh
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.xxx.com/abcd/code.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github enterprise - remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903106/github-enterprise-remote-password-authentication-is-not-available-for-git-ope)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+remote%3A+Password+authentication+is+not+available+for+Git+operations

Answer (score 4):

It's because you have cloned your repository with default https and added an SSH key to your repo.
You can do `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git` which resolves your problem.

Comment: I did set the remote url before i do add, commit & push but the error is same

Answer (score 1):

Github clone via `https` doesn't allow SSH key, so you can switch to the `git clone git@github.com/username/code.git`.

As pointed out in their [document](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/which-remote-url-should-i-use):

> The https:// clone URLs are available on all repositories, public and
>   private. These URLs work everywhere--even if you are behind a firewall
>   or proxy. In certain cases, if you'd rather use SSH, you might be able
>   to use SSH over the HTTPS port.
>
> When you git clone, git fetch, git pull, or git push to a remote
>   repository using HTTPS URLs on the command line, you'll be asked for
>   your GitHub username and password.

The point is: When you git clone, git fetch, git pull, or git push to a remote repository using HTTPS URLs on the command line, you'll be asked for
your GitHub username and password. No SSH key will be used.

It also puzzles me for weeks.